# Curve with value $0$ at $x=0$, max value $1$ at $x=1$, then decay approximating $\frac{1}{x}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, graphing-functions, curves

I want to create a curve with the above properties, and which is odd in that it is continuous, and produces a negative version of itself for negative $x$. A picture may help give the general idea (but please note it's not accurate):

[image: (Guide graphic only)]

This is created by shifting the normal (probability) curve to centre on $x=1$, then subtracting another normal curve shifted to centre on $x=-1$, using this basic formula for a normal curve:

$$\frac{e^\frac{-x^2}{2}}{\sqrt (2\pi)}$$

I then stretched the curve vertically by $\frac{\sqrt (2\pi)}{1-\frac{1}{e^2}}$ to give the curve above.

Unfortunately, it's not quite what I am looking for.

1. I want maxima and minima at $x=1$ and $x=-1$
2. I want the value of the function at those points to be $1$ and $-1$
3. I want the decay after that point to follow (at least very roughly) $\frac{1}{x}$ - i.e., far less rapid

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest function available that satisfies the given properties is a rational function:
$$\frac{2x}{1+x^2}$$
That it is odd (and so has $f(0)=0$) comes from the $x$ in the numerator. That it decays at the rate of $\frac1x$ comes from comparing the degrees of the polynomials above and below (1 vs. 2). That it has a maximum of $f(1)=1$ can be verified by differentiating the function.

[image]

Comment: +1. Added a graph (since I was in the midst of posting basically the same answer). Delete it if you object.

Comment: Far simpler! Appreciated, and marked as answered.